# Reference columns in a sqlRestriction in a criteria in a grails 3.3.9 app

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have two domains Offer and Station. I wrote a criteria query which will return all offers which are within 25000 meters of the departure Station (Offer.origin) and all possible destination Stations (Offer.stations). It works, because of a hack, which I would like to remove.

The hack is that I reference/prefix the column names latitude and longitude in the sqlRestriction by their table name aliases which I obtain by looking at the raw SQL being executed. It works, but of course if the underlying ORM implementation changes, this code will break.

I tried to reference latitude and longitude by using createAlias(), but this does not work, because they are out of the scope of the SQL code within sqlRestriction. Using {alias}.latitude {alias}.logitude will create raw SQL of "this_.latitude" "this_.longitude" which does not help either.

What subsitutes for "origin_ali1_.latitude, origin_ali1_.longitude" and "stations_a2_.latitude, stations_a2_.longitude" within the sqlRestriction?

There is a user who has a similar problem at [Hibernate Restrictions / Criteria Beginner Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136321/hibernate-restrictions-criteria-beginner-question), but I'm using grails and Offer.createCriteria() returns a BuildableCriteria instead Criteria.

Any Grails/Gorm/Hibernate Gurus out there who can solve this using the Criteria API?

```
  class Offer implements Serializable {  

    Station origin

    static hasMany = [stations: Station, bookings: Booking]

    Date startDate
    ....
  }

  class Station implements Serializable {

    BigDecimal latitude
    BigDecimal longitude
    ...
  }


  def readOffers(Thing from, Thing to, Date departureDate){

  BuildableCriteria offerCriteria = Offer.createCriteria()

  Closure c = {

  ge('endDate', new Date())

  if (departureDate != null)
  {
    sqlRestriction 'date(end_date) >= ?', [departureDate]
    sqlRestriction 'date(start_date) <= ?', [departureDate]
  }

  origin {
    sqlRestriction '(earth_distance( ll_to_earth(?, ?), ll_to_earth(origin_ali1_.latitude, origin_ali1_.longitude)) < 25000)', [from.latitude, from.longitude]
  }

  stations {
    sqlRestriction '(earth_distance( ll_to_earth(?, ?), ll_to_earth(stations_a2_.latitude, stations_a2_.longitude)) < 25000)', [to.latitude, to.longitude]
  }
}

return offerCriteria.listDistinct(c)
}
```